# left div fixed right div scrollable doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a section where a left div is fixed and the right div is scrollable but the right div content scrolls even before the scroll top reach the section. I want the right div to scroll **only when it reaches the top of the div or bottom** of the div (when scrolled up from the bottom) but it scrolls whenever it wants(inconsistent - when I scroll fast, it starts scrolling in the middle of the section, etc).

When I scroll up or down really fast, it even skips this section but **I want it to be never skipped**.

try scrolling fast and slow. the scroll works whenever it wants:

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d3aj1gx0/)

Code:

```css
.outer_div {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

.scroll-content-left {
  position: sticky;
  flex: 1 0 65%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scroll-content-left>div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}

.scroll-content-right {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  flex: 1 0 35%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 600px; background-color: blue;"></div>

<div class="outer_div">

  <div class="scroll-content-left">
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="scroll-content-right">
    <div>
      text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 600px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: What you want is to force user to scroll your whole `<div class="scroll-content-right">` before he can scroll the outer part of the page, right?

Comment: @Riccardo Yes. PLUS the window has to scroll ONLY AFTER it reaches the top of the `<div class="outer_div">`

Comment: I couldn't understand the problem you're facing, so I'll describe what I see: There's a scrollbar on the `body` element ("outer scrollbar"), and a scrollbar on the `.scroll-content-right` element ("inner scrollbar"). Trivially, they are independent of each other: [having one doesn't necessitate having the other](https://jsfiddle.net/po8vbyu1/)., and scrolling one doesn't affect the other. So what do you mean by *it scrolls whenever it wants*? Do you expect some js code to work?

Comment: https://www.source.co/how-hydropanels-work/ @OfirD If you look at this website and scroll down, you will be able to see the exact function I want. the `scroll-content-right` starts scrolling only when the scroll top reaches the TOP of its div (for me, this div is `outer_div`). But with my code, if I scroll really fast, it just skips `outer_div`(which means the `scroll-content-right` does not scroll. It skips it) and scroll to the bottom of the page. And if I scroll really slow, the `scroll-content-right` starts scrolling BEFORE the scroll top reaches the TOP of the `outer_div`.

Comment: if my answer helped you resolve your problem, could you please mark it as accepted by ticking the V icon to its left?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same effect as the one in the link you provided in the comments, you have to:

1. Remove the `overflow` property of the sticky's parent div.

- This one's worth stressing, because I think you expected otherwise, so: *You just can't have it there*. If you want to have sticky sections, there just isn't css that would make that inner scrollbar scroll.

2. Set the `top` property of the sticky div.

Read [this great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-position-sticky). From your wording I think *you* think that the `scroll-content-left` and `scroll-content-right` divs are "scrolled", but they don't; it's just that the `scroll-content-left` is sticked.

```css
.outer_div{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}


.scroll-content-left {
  position: sticky;
  flex: 1 0 65%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scroll-content-left > div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}

.scroll-content-right {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  right:0;
  flex: 1 0 35%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 600px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="outer_div">
        <div class="scroll-content-left"><div>
        </div></div>
        <div class="scroll-content-right">
          <div> text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div style="height: 600px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg59eqd6/).

Comment: Setting only the left div sticky solved the issue. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; font-size:12px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 15px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
 
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want the sidebar to be always shown. I want the section of "sidenav" AND the "text" in the middle of other divs and then disappear when I scroll down or up like the JSFiddle I linked.